# Requiring Unique Versions of Modules

Tags: node.js, logging

Imagine I have a very simple logging program.  I store it in a file so it can be reused, let's call this file `logger.js` (original, I know).  All this program does, is it logs whatever is given to it, with another string that is given to it during initialisation.  A really simple implementation of it might look like this:

```
var logger = function () {}
var moduleName = ''

logger.prototype.init = function (name) {
  moduleName = name
}

logger.prototype.log = function (msg) {
  console.log(moduleName + ' ' + msg)
}

module.exports = new logger()
```

Now, I'm going to want to use this logging mechanism in multiple files, with multiple different names initialised.  I might have `app.js`:

```
var logger = require('./logger.js')
logger.init('App.js')
logger.log('Hello, World From App.js!')

var module = require('./module.js')

logger.log('Hello, World 2 From App.js!')
```

Whereupon it requires the logger, prints out an original message, requires `module.js` (another module), before logging something different.  A simple `module.js`:

```
var logger2 = require('./logger.js')
logger2.init('Module.js')
logger2.log('Hello, World From Module.js!')
```

When these are run, one would hope for this to be output:

```
App.js Hello, World From App.js!
Module.js Hello, World From Module.js!
App.js Hello, World 2 From App.js!
```

However, instead I get (note the last line is coming from `app.js`, but displaying that it is coming from `module.js`):

```
App.js Hello, World From App.js!
Module.js Hello, World From Module.js!
Module.js Hello, World 2 From App.js!
```

Is there a way I can get it so that the logger modules are unique, so that when I initialise one copy with a value it doesn't mess with the other versions of logger.  One would expect, considering I'm requiring them to different variables, that they should be unique, and initialising one would not affect the other, however this does not seem to be the case.

Also, at a best case scenario, logically there should be a way to have them all be under the variable name of `logger`.  They should all be out of scope of one another (I hope).

Comment: Instead of exporting a single logger object why not export the logger function and create a new one in the file that imports it?

Answer (score 2):

Node.js caches the code from `logger.js`, and you only have one `logger` (created in the line `module.exports = new logger()`).

You can change your code slightly to get the desired functionality.
In `logger.js`:

```
module.exports = function(m){ var l = new logger(); l.init(m); return l };
```

In other modules:

```
var logger = require('./logger.js')('Module.js')
logger.log('Hello, World 2 From App.js!')
```

That way you will have different logger every time you call `require('./logger.js')(moduleName)`.

Comment: Hm, I've made your suggested edits, which do look like they should work, however I'm still getting the same output.  [Edits](https://gist.github.com/popey456963/59b342cf4e713a224828)